# Partial Image source binding with extra text in windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, azure, windows-phone-8

I want to bind an USER ID to image source but the absolute link must be there. how can  do that?

so i want : www.aaaa.com/userid.jpg there
my code is here.

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="userfeed" CacheMode="{x:Null}" Margin="-20,0,-20,10" LayoutMode="List"  Background="white" BorderBrush="#FFE6E6E6" Foreground="#FF171717" >
                            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,5,0,0">

                              <image x:name="test" source="{binding id}" />  // <- i want here absolute path how can i bind/type extra text?

                                    </StackPanel>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a view model class with a `UserId` property, you might simply add another readonly property like `UserImageUrl`:

```
public class User
{
    private string userId;

    public string UserId
    {
        get { return userId; }
        set
        {
            userId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
            OnPropertyChanged("UserImageUrl");
        }
    }

    public string UserImageUrl
    {
        get { return string.Format("http://www.aaaa.com/{0}.jpg", userId); }
    }
}
```

Then bind to that new property like

```
<Image Source="{Binding UserImageUrl}" />
```

Comment: Hard coding the URL root is a bad idea. What if it changes dynamically or is pulled from a database?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post all of your code I have to speculate what the User ID property looks like but I would do something like this...

This is your xaml

```
<image x:name="test" source="{binding ImageSource}" />
```

And this is what you add to your CS file

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private String _id;

public String id
{
   get{
        return _id;       
   }
   set{
       _id= value; OnPropertyChanged("id");OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
   }
}


private String _RootURL;

public String RootURL
{
   get{
        return _RootURL;     
   }
   set{
       _RootURL = value; OnPropertyChanged("RootURL"); OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
   }
}

private String _ImageSource;

public String ImageSource
{
   get{
        return RootURL+ id;       
   }
}

PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

void OnPropertyChanged(String prop){
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if(handler!=null){
    PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
  }
}
}
```

## Edited based on Clemens response

I wanted to tailor this original answer toward a green developer. However, as Clemens pointed out in the comments it wasn't the technical way to do it. The updated solution I have posted is a much better choice than a converter. Converters are traditionally used when converting database values or other random, non-user friendly data, into useful data. For example, if you had 0's and 1's in your database table but you wanted to display blue or orange in their place. This is an excellent reason to use a converter.

Using a converter to concatenate strings on the other hand is a poor use of them. Being that if you have to change the URL you must go to your converter to do it. The reason that my answer is superior is because it allows you to set the Root URL from any source you'd like. Such as a database or web JSON response. Then, you bind your Image to the ImageSource property which concatenates it all together.

Comment: very good idea thanks, its in the class and longlistselector, so when class deserialize and list binds to longlistselector the source will do like ths right? for every different id?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032123/1136211) why this *not* such a good idea. Add *another* (readonly) property for the URL or use a binding converter instead.

Comment: @user3565698 Online documentation on MSDN: [Binding.Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter).